# Friendship between users in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent, relationship

I have created model so that users can be friends. I have table user_friends where user_id and friend_id are stored. The problem is, that it works only one-way. If user 1 adds user 2 as friend, user 2 will be friend of user 1 but not reverse (user 1 friend of user 2) how can I accomplish something like this?

User model

```
   public function friends()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('User','user_friends','user_id','friend_id');
}
```

and User_Friend model

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('User');
}
```

Finding friends

```
 $friends = User::find($user->id)->friends;
```

And part of controller where I save new friendship

```
$friendData = array('user_id' => $invite->id,); //$invite is result of $invite->save()
        $friend = User::find($user->id)->friends()->attach($friendData);
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the framework in question but you could do something like... `SELECT friend_id FROM user_friends WHERE user_id = ? UNION SELECT user_id FROM user_friends WHERE friend_id = ?`. That should give you a list of all friends no matter which way the link goes.

Comment: This is one solution. But Laravel and Eloquent are using different approach. Sorry I can't accept your answer.

Comment: Not a problem, I know it's not the solution you're after, that's why it wasn't an answer just a comment.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is store and the reverse relationship.

```
$friendData = ['user_id' => $invite->id];

$user = User::find($user->id);
$user->friends()->attach($friendData);

$friend = User::find($invite->id);
$friend->friends()->attach($user);
```

Otherwise you may retrieve the reverse relationship

```
public function reverseFriends()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('User', 'User_Friend', 'friend_id', 'user_id');
}
```

and then merge the two collections.